# Google app engine and paging

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

How would one go about writing a query that selects items 2000-2010 out of a collection of 10000 objects in the data store.

I know that it can be done like this in GQL:

```
select * from MyObject limit 10 offset 2000
```

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html), when using an `offset` the engine will still fetch all the rows, only not return them, thus making the query perform in a way that corresponds linearly with the value of `offset`.

Is there any better way? Such as using a pseudo `ROWNUM` column like one could do in other types of data stores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to efficiently page using offsets, except to cache the results. You can, however, use [datastore cursors](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors) to implement paging using a 'bookmark' type approach.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using cursors you can also use a sort order approach. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyObject ORDER BY field LIMIT 10;
```

for the first 10 objects and then for the next 10 objects, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM MyObject WHERE field > largestFieldValueFromPreviousResult ORDER BY field LIMIT 10;
```

Field could even be a key if you don't have another appropriate field. Here is a more complete example:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/paging.html